# Avoid aggregate function in decision making in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to check the variable value using `IF` condition 
Based on my variable value, I need to write the crud operations.
I am using the below condition

```
DECLARE @MyVal VARCHAR(10) = '9EA4DF9A51E'

IF (@MyVal IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@MyVal) > 0)
BEGIN
    --  I will write my CRUD operation statements here
END
```

I can also change the above **IF** condition as

```
IF @MyVal IS NOT NULL AND @MyVal <> ''
```

Can anyone suggest which one is good to use or both statements are having same result performance wise?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see any *aggregate* function anywhere in your code sample .... but I'd typically pick the second option in my own code base

Comment: Also: you've defined your `@MyVal` as `VARCHAR(*10*)` - yet you set it to a string of **11** characters length ....

Comment: `IF @MyVal IS NOT NULL AND @MyVal <> ''` is the same as `IF @MyVal <> ''`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, asking about performance is not very welcomed here, as everyone (me, you, anybody) can do some benchmarks on local machine, where this code will run and this is best benchmark you can get.

But talking about result:

```
IF (@MyVal IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@MyVal) > 0)
```

is: if value is not null OR if its length is greater than 0 (so it has some characters).

So if value is empty, but not null, it would be `true OR false` which is `true`.

This statement

```
IF @MyVal IS NOT NULL AND @MyVal <> ''
```

Let's again consider empty value, then this expression would be `true AND false` which is false.

So you have two different results, SO they are not equivalent.

Performance-wise I would not worry much, as it won't differ much.